# Is there a way to add a button in an askopenfile dialog window?

Tags: python, tkinter, openfiledialog

So this is the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x100')


def printer():
    print("hello")
```

In the browse function im creating an askopenfile dialog window that allows me to choose a file with the button "Open"

```
def browse():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=win, mode='rb', title='Choose a file')
    if file is not None:
        file.close()
```

In this browse function i would like an extra button next to the "Open" button that would say "Print" for example and would trigger the printer function from above

```
browse_button = Button(win, text="Browse", command=browse)
browse_button.pack(pady=100 / 10)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Take a read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html)

Comment: I'm still kind of a beginner and not used to the whole tkinter thing so I can't really figure out how to fulfill my desire. I would appreciate a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Actually I don't think you can. You have to make your own custom filedialog that has this extra buttons.